# Exclude Test dependencies and plugin dependencies in maven copy dependencies command

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Maven copy dependencies command is not excluding the dependencies mentioned as part of plugins. Is there a way to exclude them? I am using the following command?

One such plugin in pom.xml

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime -Dmdep.skip=true 
-Dsilent=true
```

The objective is to copy only the jars and transitive jars shipped in a spring boot jar. Are there any alternate ways to do this?

Comment: Simply unpack the spring boot jar which has been created...furthermore why would you like to copy them? For what purpose?

Comment: I need to copy the dependencies separately to scan for security issues.

Comment: Something like OWASP / ossindex ?

Comment: Something like oss index. But it's done against a centralized library.

Comment: So you can do that on the fly no need to copy dependencies to a particular location.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to provide the dependencies and they run it against another software. I don't want to provide test and plugin dependencies as they are not shipped inside the uber jar.